# Error when editing a row in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my mvc site i have a page which display the details of users in a table format and there is a link to edit the selected row, when clicking on edit it display error message as shown below

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'regNo' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UserEdit(Int32)' in 'Sample_MVCApp.Controllers.UserController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

code is given below

model:

```
public class UserModels
{
    [Key]
    public int RegNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="First name required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Date field is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DateRange(ErrorMessage = "Must be between 18 and 65 years ago")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    [Range(100,10000)]
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult UserEdit(int regNo)
    {
        Users user = new Users();
        return View(user.GetUserDetailsForEdit(regNo));
    }
```

page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>UserModels</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegNo)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

in my index page i use the below line to get the id

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserEdit", new { id=item.RegNo })
```

when click on edit , the parameter value is null, but the url contains the value as
"/User/UserEdit/3"

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action method parameter name is not matching with ActionLink parameter name.
Change

```
public ActionResult UserEdit(int regNo)
```

to

```
public ActionResult UserEdit(int id)
```

Or Change your Action Link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserEdit", new { id=item.RegNo })
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserEdit", new { regNo=item.RegNo })
```

It should work.

Comment: thanks for the post, I have a doubt, is the regNo in method is a variable, so should i use the same variable name?

Comment: Yes both name in Actionlink and Action Method need to be matched.